# Kubernetes admin segregation

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-operator

Most of the kubernetes operators require the ability to create cluster roles, cluster role bindings, and crds.

I want a proper rbac segregation, and I want to avoid to put the deployment service account directly as an admin.

But if I only give it the cluster role edition permissions, it seems that it allows it to put itself admin in the end.

What is the proper way to deal with that? (if there is one).

Comment: You can have namespaces and have service accounts with access to only the specific resources and apiGroups that you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can have namespaces and have service accounts with access to only the specific resources and apiGroups that you want.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: gitlab-tez-dev # account name
  namespace: tez-dev #namespace

---
kind: Role
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1
metadata:
  name: tez-dev-full-access #role
  namespace: tez-dev
rules:
  - apiGroups: ["", "extensions", "apps"]
    resources: ["deployments", "replicasets", "pods", "services"] #resources to which permissions are granted
    verbs: ["*"] # what actions are allowed
---
kind: RoleBinding
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1
metadata:
  name: tez-dev-view
  namespace: tez-dev
subjects:
  - kind: ServiceAccount
    name: gitlab-tez-dev
    namespace: tez-dev
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: Role
  name: tez-dev-full-access
```

So the above role does not have cluster access and it's access if limited to the defined namespace and to the specific resources and actions that are specified.

You can then use it for deployment in the defined namespace.

Comment: I'm aware of that :), my concern is that for something like ambassador, I need to create cluster role and cluster role binding which are not scoped to a namespace..

Comment: You didn't mention this in your question. Something like ambassador needs cluster-role binding as it spans across namespaces. And I don't think there is any way around that. Others may correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen how it's done in case of [prometheus-operator](https://coreos.com/operators/prometheus/docs/latest/user-guides/getting-started.html) ?
It avoids giving deployment service account the full admin rights, especially to let it control permission to perform actions 'create/bind' on roles or clusterroles resources in the 'rbac.authorization.k8s.io' API group.
I think you can use it as a good reference scheme for setting up separate RBAC rules for an operated App and App-Operator.